# Get the same java object on saving that object in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java

MY POJO looks like this:

```
@Document(collection = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    private String id;

    String username;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

I am able to save the object's values in the mongodb by calling `mongoDBClient.save(userObj);` as bellow:

```
public void save(Object paramObject) {
        mongoOperations.save(paramObject);
    }
```

The problem with this `save` api is that it's returning `void`. I want to get the same object which was saved. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`paramObject` is viable for introspection after save. It represents it's persistent state at that stage.

For example, the driver is responsible to assign the `id` on your behalf.

In addition, all properties which you don't set yourself and are designated to be populated by spring data - such as properties annotated with `@CreatedDate` - are also available after the `save()` method (assuming auditing is configured).

In any case, the Id is set. Later you can query for the same object by calling `findById(paramObject.getId(), User.class)`

Comment: Yes!, The data/new data persist after save. Thanks!